# Remove a subview from a UITableViewCell's content view

Tags: uiview, uitableview

How do I remove a Subview from a UITableViewCell's content view?

For instance, I have added the following subview to my cell's content view.

```
UIButton *b = etc.
[cell.contentView addSubview:b];
```

Now I'd like to remove it:
?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This code remove all subviews on cell:

```
 if ([cell.contentView subviews]){
    for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews]) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One line

```
[cell.contentView.subviews makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperview)];
```